# Calculating a camera's position and orientation in opencv

Tags: opencv

So imagine that there is a camera looking at your computer screen.  What I am trying to do is determine how much that camera is rotated, how far away it is from the screen, and where it is relative to the screen's center.  In short the rotation and translation matrices.

I'm using opencv to do this, and followed their camera calibration example to do this task with a checkerboard pattern and a frame from a webcam.  I would like to do with any generic images, namely a screen cap and a frame from a webcam.

I've tried using the feature detection algorithms to get a list of keypoints from both images and then match those keypoints with a BFMatcher, but have run into problems.  Specifically SIFT does not match keypoints correctly, and SURF does not find keypoints correctly on a scaled image.

Is there an easier solution to this problem?  I feel that this would be a common thing that people have done, but have not found much discussion of it online.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you try to find your screen in the image, and find the outline? Then, you can find the rotation and the translation because you know the screen's actual size, and the size it appears in the image, and you also know the screen's .skewed shape in the image, compared with the rectangular shape in real life. Hmmm.... Interesting question. +1

Comment: This a good question as this is not the typical planar marker task. +1

Comment: @eboix, any chance you could share the technique(s) involved in using the known world geometry and the skewed image geometry to determine the orientation and position? I'm trying to do do the same thing however instead of a computer screen I'm using ceiling lights, which are of known size.

Answer (score 5):

Finding natural planar markers is a common task in computer vision but in your case you have a screen which varies depending on what you are visualizing on the screen, it can be your desktop, your browser, a movie,...

So you cannot apply usual methods for marker detection, you should try shape recognition. An idea is trying a *particle filter* on a rectangular template of the same dimensions (through different scales) of your screen frame, applying first edge detection.

The particle filter will fit the template to the area of the frame. After doing this, you will know the position. For orientation you will need to calculate homography, and you need 4 points in the "marker" for this, so you can apply Direct Linear Transform (cv::findHomography() does this for you). So your four points can be the four corners.
This is just an idea, good luck!

Comment: Here you have some slides explainign a similar aplication of the particle filter. It is matching a more general template and works fine, so for your applycation will perform better as the size is always the same:  http://www.slideshare.net/Javier_Barbadillo/single-person-pose-recognition-and-tracking-7742854

Comment: It won't necessarily be the same scale though.  For instance when the camera is looking "down" the screen from off to the side, the width will be longer than when the camera is looking straight on.